# cqlsh having issue executing using cqlsh -e

Tags: shell, cassandra, cqlsh

I'm having hard time executing using -e option with column name is in quotes.

I want to execute some thing like below using unix level.  Trying to run from shell script.  When i try to put my values in quotes, its taking away the quotes for my column.

```
select * from keyspace.cf where "columnname"=''
```

Tried this:

```
cqlsh hostname -e "select * from keyspace.cf where "columnname"=''"
```

It is executing as cqlsh hostname -e 'select * from keyspace.cf where columnname='

```
stdin>:1:InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Undefined name columnaname in where clause ('columnname= 'value'')"
```

Comment: Why do you want to enclose column name with quote ? and what is your table schema ?

Comment: `cqlsh hostname -e "select * from keyspace.cf where columnname='' "`... you don't need double quotes for columnname (until columnname is in capital letters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to put quotes around `columnname`, you just need to set it and prefix it with a $.

```
cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra -e "SELECT $COLUMN FROm $KEYSPACE.$TABLE;"
```

That's an excerpt from a script I wrote called `getVersion.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash

KEYSPACE="system"
TABLE="local"
COLUMN="release_version"

~/local/apache-cassandra-3.10/bin/cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra -e "SELECT $COLUMN FROm $KEYSPACE.$TABLE;"

aploetz@dockingBay94:~/scripts$ ./getVersion.sh 

 release_version
-----------------
            3.10

(1 rows)
```

The same will work if your column names contain quotes.  Just be sure to escape them in your variable definition.  This is a similar script, but it queries the `"columnName" TEXT` column:

```
#!/bin/bash

KEYSPACE="stackoverflow"
TABLE="stuff_with_quotes"
COLUMN="\"columnName\""

~/local/apache-cassandra-3.10/bin/cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra -e "SELECT $COLUMN FROm $KEYSPACE.$TABLE;"
```